# How does the eureka client find the eureka server in spring boot 1.5.2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-service-registration-and-discovery) and I don't see any configuration for the location / url of the eureka server (Only the `src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties` containing the name of the eureka client), so how does this client know where the Eureka server is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is using default eureka server address `http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka`.
If you don't specify any property like below, eureka client will try to connect `http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka` and eureka server is running on 8761 port as default.

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka
```

Comment: Can we get more depth answer on this. I mean how the eureka client find the eureka server with default address too? What mechanism it is following to look at the default address and how it is happening all internally?